# Water Flow Rate

Tags: applications

I am doing a software development code to dispense water for which I need to find the its flow rate.

The tank can hold around $300$ liters of water and has only a $1/2$" inch ($.75$ cm inch diameter) pipe ($6$ inches length) as outlet. I would be installing a flow sensor to this pipe to measure water dispensed. As per the sensor the Min and Max flow rate should be $1-30$ liters per minutes.

Can anyone please let me know if this flow sensor is ok for my software setup? What is the min and max water flow rate via this $1/2$" pipe when tank is full / half / below half. I am not sure how to calculate flow rate.

Comment: what are the dimensions of the tank.

Comment: Flow rate/speed is basically because of the pressure difference generated due to difference in the elevation of two points i.e point of outlet and the free surface.

Comment: The dimensions of tank are l = 3ft, w=3ft and h= 2ft

Comment: Can anyone please provide the flow control - thanks in advance